# How to direct to previosly viewed page like in browsers?

Tags: php, javascript

I have a back button in my site. If I click on back button it should display previously viewed page.

example:I checked second project first then tenth project now if I click back button it should redirect to second project page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use javascript history.back

```
window.history.back();  // this takes u one page backward
```

check this out

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Answer (score 1):

in Javascript you can do in this way

for single step

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

and for two

```
window.history.go(-2);
```

and so on....

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged this with PHP there is also another option besides javascript
    window.history.go(-1);

In PHP you could use the 'HTTP_REFERER' in the $_SERVER array
    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

The var is however send to PHP by the user agent and not all user agents do this, check http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for more information.